# Adding hyperlink to Excel while using Jexcelapi JAVA library

Tags: java, excel, hyperlink

I am writing an application in Java that uses JexcelAPI to create an Excel 2003 file, write data into it (17 columns, 15,000 rows). The data is received from a reliable data stream. So far so good - it works perfectly.
The problem started when I tried to place hypertext in some of the cells (actually in one column). From this minute on the file saving failed.
The code:

```
public class partsData 
{
   private final static String PdbFileName = "partsDB.xls";
   private static WorkbookSettings PdbWorkSheet = null;
   private static WritableWorkbook PdbWorkbook = null;
   private static WritableSheet PdbWritableSheet = null;

   WritableHyperlink wh = null;

   public static void main (String args[])
   {
      Int linesCounter = 2;
      try 
      { 
         PdbWorkSheet = new WorkbookSettings();
         PdbWorkbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(PdbFileName), PdbWorkSheet);
         PdbWritableSheet = PdbWorkbook.createSheet(PdbFileName, 0);
      } 
      catch (IOException e) { filesClose("File open failed - program aborts\n"); }

      try 
      { // Write to the cells
        lr = new Label(10, linesCounter, splitLine[0]);
        PdbWritableSheet.addCell(lr);
    }
        catch (WriteException e) { logFileWrite("Write failure - #" + linesCounter); }

// Create hyperlink fields based on the data already embedded in the Excel
       String sStr = <File name and path>
       String tStr = <field text>

       if ((sStr != "") && (tStr != "") && (linesCounter > 1))
       {
         file = new File (sStr);
            wh = new WritableHyperlink(4, linesCounter, file);
         try { PdbWritableSheet.addHyperlink(wh); }
         catch (RowsExceededException e) { logFileWrite("REE); }
         catch (WriteException e) { logFileWrite("WE); }
       }
       else
         logFileWrite("No hyperlink");
      }

      try
      {
         PdbWorkbook.write();  // This is where the exception occurs
         PdbWorkbook.close();
      }
      catch (IOException | WriteException e) { logFileWrite("close failure); };
      logFileWrite(message);         
   }
}
```

The error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at jxl.write.biff.HyperlinkRecord.getFileData(HyperlinkRecord.java:1011)
    at jxl.write.biff.HyperlinkRecord.getData(HyperlinkRecord.java:518)
    at jxl.biff.WritableRecordData.getBytes(WritableRecordData.java:71)
    at jxl.write.biff.File.write(File.java:147)
    at jxl.write.biff.SheetWriter.write(SheetWriter.java:570)
```

any help will be appreciated
Regards
Ganish